# Why I cannot resume uploading a video to youtube with a refreshed access token?

Tags: youtube

I'm attempting to use the resumable API to upload a video to YouTube with a refreshed access token.  but I'm getting a 401 back when I've finished uploading the resumed part of the data. I get the following message back alongside the 401:

authError Invalid Credentials

But I can upload a new video with that refresh access token.

Comment: Can you post here your code as well?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug on the server-side: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14320908/1970843, https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/issues/detail?id=231, https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5124