# Google Drive SDK / c++ / Rest API resumable upload

Tags: c++, qt, google-drive-api, resume-upload

I have seen discussion in internet about problems (or bugs in Google Drive SDK ) with resumable uploading to google Drive 
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#resumable

and the problem with access_token when it expires after one hour ..

Is there a possibility now ( I understood there should be ) to refresh access token for this ongoing upload ?

I did the test implementation for this but it did not work, when I updated the refreshed access token?

but is this now bug in my code or google drive side ?

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14286402/1970843

Answer (score 1):

If you abandon the library, and simply call the REST API directly, you can implement your own 401 error handling.

**edit; see comments below which suggest that the problem is a bug which cannot be circumvented**

Comment: I am calling REST API directly , and then when "unauthrorized error" comes, I get new access token with help of refresh token, and then try to use that in coming requests .. but that does not seem to go as I thought. So you have managet to get this working okay?

Comment: How are you using the access token and what error are you getting?

Comment: 1. First sending post request with uploadType resumable with content length and X-Upload-Content-Length and -Type
   2. Then from the response I pick the "location" url from header
   3. Then start sending chunks of files in put requests to "location url" and putting Content-Range header to request
   4. Then when failure comes after 1 hour, I get the new access token , update it to "location" url and continue, and this continuation fails

Comment: the two failures in step 4 are both 401? 

Can you paste the url after you've updated it? 

have you tried setting the access token as an HTTP header rather than encode it in the URL?

Comment: Yes , errors were the same. Putting access token to HTTP header I have not tried yet and I have not seen the documentation to tell to do it that way. I saw similar issue ( https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5124 ) as reported error, not sure if that could be the same issue . So you have not done the similar impl yet  ?

Comment: Just read the bug report and it seems to match your symptoms. It's prob worth trying to set the auth header (Authorization: Bearer access_token) just in case. Otherwise star the bug and wait ... and wait

Comment: It's pretty mich the same issue you've found in the issue tracker. The problem is on the drive/YouTube endpoint and can't be fixed with code. Use Api v2 and take this bug, or switch back to probably working Api v1 if possible.

Comment: Dennis Fischer , question about your comment "use Api v2 and take this bug?" what did you mean by that, reporting error somewhere ?

Comment: so is there any activity at Google Drive / Google team related to this ? Quite an annoying  error and I would hope to see some comments what's going on with this