# How to upload big file to google drive using requests in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I have code that uploads my archive to Google Drive using my access token and requests, but if the file is larger than 512MB, it will fail with exit code **MemoryError**, so I'm searching for a way to fix this error and upload a file larger than 512MB. I already tried to find a solution but I didn't find anything where I could use an access token.

```
import os
import json
import requests
import ntpath
import oauth2
import httplib2
import oauth2client
from contextlib import closing
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

_CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
_CLIENT_SECRET = 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET'
_REFRESH_TOKEN = 'YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN'
_PARENT_FOLDER_ID = 'YOUR_PARENT_FOLDER_ID'
_ARCHIVE_FILE = os.environ['USERPROFILE'] +'\\Desktop\\WobbyChip.zip'


# ====================================================================================

def GetAccessToken(client_id, client_secret, refresh_token):
    cred = oauth2client.client.GoogleCredentials(None,client_id,client_secret,refresh_token,None,'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',None)
    http = cred.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    cred.refresh(http)
    obj = json.loads(cred.to_json())
    _ACCESS_TOKEN = obj['access_token']
    return _ACCESS_TOKEN


def UploadFile(local_file, parent_folder_id, access_token,):
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +access_token}
    para = {
        'name': (ntpath.basename(local_file)),
        'parents': [parent_folder_id]}
    files = {
        'data': ('metadata', json.dumps(para), 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'),
        'file': open(local_file, 'rb')}
    requests.post(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart',
        headers=headers,
        files=files)

# ====================================================================================


if __name__ == '__main__':
    UploadFile(_ARCHIVE_FILE, _PARENT_FOLDER_ID, GetAccessToken(_CLIENT_ID, _CLIENT_SECRET, _REFRESH_TOKEN))
```

Comment: Are you sure Google *allows* you to do this?

Comment: @Temporaly For example, is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/14286402/7108653

Comment: I think you will need to use chunked upload. it's trying to open and upload the file in one instance and running out of memory

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks to you I have, you really helped I used this post and edited my code, so now I'm able to upload the file larger than 512MB, but I have new problem I don't know how to include parent folder id (folder id where the file will be uploaded) in body