# How to make file upload to specified folder directly using folder parent id

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, google-api-client

After I figured out how to upload a file bigger than 512MB, I found another one problem, I don't know how to make my file upload to a specified folder using folder parent id.

In my previous code I could upload the file directly to the folder, but now I can't

```
import os
import httplib2
import zipfile
import ntpath
import oauth2client
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow

# Copy your credentials here
_CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
_CLIENT_SECRET = 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET'
_REFRESH_TOKEN = 'YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN'
_PARENT_FOLDER_ID = 'YOUR_PARENT_FOLDER_ID'

# ====================================================================================

# Upload file to Google Drive
def UploadFile(client_id, client_secret, refresh_token, local_file, parent_folder_id):
    cred = oauth2client.client.GoogleCredentials(None,client_id,client_secret,refresh_token,None,'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',None)
    http = cred.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
    media_body = MediaFileUpload(local_file, mimetype='application/octet-stream', chunksize=10485760, resumable=True)
    body = {
        'title': (ntpath.basename(local_file)),
        'parents': [parent_folder_id], # <-- Here is the problem, actualy i don't know how to make it upload to specified folder directly
        'mimeType': 'application/octet-stream'
    }
    request = drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body)
    response = None
    while response is None:
        status, response = request.next_chunk()
        if status:
                print "Uploaded %.2f%%" % (status.progress() * 100)
    print "Upload Complete!"

# ====================================================================================


if __name__ == '__main__':
    UploadFile(_CLIENT_ID, _CLIENT_SECRET, _REFRESH_TOKEN, 'bigfile.zip', _PARENT_FOLDER_ID)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, it is found that you are trying to use Drive API v2 from `drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)` and the request body. I think that there are 2 patterns for your modification.

### Pattern 1:

When you use Drive API v2, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
'parents': [parent_folder_id]
```

#### To:

```
'parents': [{'id': parent_folder_id}]}
```

### Pattern 2:

When you use Drive API v3, please modify as follows. In this case, you can use `'parents': [parent_folder_id]`. But other parts are required to modify for v3.

#### From:

```
drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
media_body = MediaFileUpload(local_file, mimetype='application/octet-stream', chunksize=10485760, resumable=True)
body = {
    'title': (ntpath.basename(local_file)),
    'parents': [parent_folder_id],
    'mimeType': 'application/octet-stream'
}
request = drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body)
```

#### To:

```
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', http=http)  # Modified
media_body = MediaFileUpload(local_file, mimetype='application/octet-stream', chunksize=10485760, resumable=True)
body = {
    'name': (ntpath.basename(local_file)),  # Modified
    'parents': [parent_folder_id],
    'mimeType': 'application/octet-stream'
}
request = drive_service.files().create(body=body, media_body=media_body)  # Modified
```

#### Note:

- About [your previous code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54698923), in this script, Drive API v3 is used. But when I saw the thread I introduced to you, Drive API v2 was used.

#### References:

- [Files: insert of Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)
- [Files: create of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)